# Removing File Extensions from Website URLs in Replit

Tags: html, replit

So I want to make my website url `https://games.hollodev.repl.co/home.html` into `https://games.hollodev.repl.co/home` how do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You would typically want to use some kind of simple backend like `express` or `flask`.

For example if you were to use `express` in node.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// '/home' route would render your html file.
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/home.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```